# Getting musical notations using aubio library

Tags: fft, aubio

Well, this is my first question on stackoverflow so kinda excited about it :)
Here it is: My input is a wave file. For now, I have recorded a piece using my guitar. So the wave file contains this instrumental recording. What I want to do is, get the musical notation(A,B,C and so on) of each note that is being played. I have heard about techniques like the FFT but considering my poor knowledge of how to use FFT, I thought of using the [aubio](http://aubio.org/) library.

So aubio provides:
aubiopitch which extracts pitch candidates and
aubiocut which extracts onsets.

Where I am stuck is: How do I get the frequency at the particular **time** of the note played using aubio?
According to me, aubiopitch and aubiocut would help but I dont understand how to do the mapping between them. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

---

Hi piem: Thanks for your answer. Could you please analyse this output?

`aubiopitch -i Reverse_Open.wav`

> 1.408  68.9486465454
>
> 1.536  81.7372512817
>
> 1.664  164.290893555
>
> 1.792  164.464691162
>
> 1.92   82.6862487793
>
> 2.048  328.539306641
>
> 2.176  218.885116577
>
> 2.304  219.06237793
>
> 2.432  219.042160034
>
> 2.56   219.133621216
>
> 2.688  145.751785278
>
> 2.816  146.437744141
>
> 2.944  146.199829102
>
> 3.072  195.059829712
>
> 3.2    194.912689209
>
> 3.328  195.724975586
>
> 3.456  195.517547607
>
> 3.584  247.317428589
>
> 3.712  246.764221191
>
> 3.84   246.857452393
>
> 3.968  145.454727173
>
> 4.096  328.569610596
>
> 4.224  329.625823975
>
> 4.352  329.16619873
>
> 4.48   328.906402588
>
> 4.608  328.96786499
>
> 4.736  329.187835693
>
> 4.864  145.741394043

My notes with frequencies are: `E(82 approx),A(110),D(147),G(197),B(247),E(329.2)`
which are played at `1.344,1.888,2.4,2.88,3.36,3.872` resp(according to aubiopitch which I suppose is correct).
Any idea how do I extract these 6 notes and their times from the above output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aubiopitch outputs a list of tuple. Each tuple contains two floats:

- a timestamp in seconds
- a fundamental frequency in Hertz

Here is an example on a guitar sound:

```
$ aubiopitch -i guitar_Cold_Blood_-_Baby_I_Love_You.wav | head
0.000000 0.000000
0.005805 293.884338
0.011610 386.387207
0.017415 0.000000
0.023220 551.689758
0.029025 3608.569336
0.034830 3588.231201
0.040635 416.824066
0.046440 3606.715576
0.052245 417.116425
```

if you are curious (please be), you can get the latest git version and try the demo script `demo_pitch.py`:

```
$ ./python/demos/demo_pitch.py bass_Don_Ellis_-_Conquistador.wav
```

you would get the following plot:

[image: aubio pitch demo plot]

- The first row represents the waveform.
- The second row, the extracted pitch track, in midi frequency.
- The third, the confidence of these pitch candidates (using the yinfft algorithm).

In this sample of a bass line, extracting the pitch during the transient attacks is more challenging than in the steady state. Pitch candidates that are found below an arbitrary threshold (here 0.8) can be discarded (dashed green line), while others can be kept (solid blue line).

Comment: @sarju, if you want to extract notes, you could use a median filter over the pitch candidates to determine long section with almost constant pitch. This is what `aubionotes` does, also combining the pitches with onsets.

Comment: piem: Got the notes. Thanks a lot! I had actually read about aubionotes but somehow missed that the output was in MIDI and got deviated from it. Thanks for pointing it out :) Works perfect now.